# Some Markdown content doesn't work within a <sub> tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

On [Why would one replace default new and delete operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149461/why-would-one-replace-default-new-and-delete-operators), the Note section's links and italics aren't correctly rendered:

[image: Screenshot of the question's note]

That section is wrapped in `<sub>`.

I've edited it to use HTML tags, but **should** Markdown work within `<sub>`? I don't really see why not.

Comment: I've used markdown within sub tags successfully many times, [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722). Maybe it's because you put the tags on separate lines, whereas I generally write `<sub>some text including markdown</sub>` on a single line?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes, seems the newline is related. More specifically the one at the start. Having a newline before the closing tag doesn't seem to affect it. [See in the formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/396990)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Why this happens

This happens because the Markdown that begins with a line which is `<sub>` by itself qualifies as:

> 7. **Start condition:** line begins with a complete [open tag](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.31.2/#open-tag) (with any [tag name](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.31.2/#tag-name) other than `pre`, `script`, `style`, or `textarea`) or a complete [closing tag](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.31.2/#closing-tag), followed by zero or more spaces and tabs, followed by the end of the line.
>    <sub><sub>From [CommonMark Specification 0.31.2: 4.6 HTML blocks](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.31.2/#html-blocks)</sub></sub>

for starting an [HTML Block](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.31.2/#html-blocks), which "is a group of lines that is treated as raw HTML (and will not be escaped in HTML output)."

So, this is definitely working as specified [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

#### Examples

The Markdown text which you're concerned about renders the same on the [official CommonMark test site](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%3Csub%3E%0ANote%3A%20%20The%20answer%20is%20based%20on%20lessons%20from%20Scott%20Meyers%27%20More%20Effective%20C%2B%2B.%20%20%0A_(Note%3A%20This%20is%20meant%20to%20be%20an%20entry%20to%20%5BStack%20Overflow%27s%20C%2B%2B%20FAQ%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fc%2B%2B-faq).%20If%20you%20want%20to%20critique%20the%20idea%20of%20providing%20an%20FAQ%20in%20this%20form%2C%20then%20%5Bthe%20posting%20on%20meta%20that%20started%20all%20this%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F68647%2Fsetting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag)%20would%20be%20the%20place%20to%20do%20that.%20Answers%20to%20that%20question%20are%20monitored%20in%20the%20%5BC%2B%2B%20chatroom%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fchat.stackoverflow.com%2Frooms%2F10%2Fc-lounge)%2C%20where%20the%20FAQ%20idea%20started%20out%20in%20the%20first%20place%2C%20so%20your%20answer%20is%20very%20likely%20to%20get%20read%20by%20those%20who%20came%20up%20with%20the%20idea.)_%0A%3C%2Fsub%3E) as it does in [that revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7149461/9). The Markdown is interpreted if the [opening `<sub>` is on the same line as the first line of subscript text](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%3Csub%3ENote%3A%20%20The%20answer%20is%20based%20on%20lessons%20from%20Scott%20Meyers%27%20More%20Effective%20C%2B%2B.%20%20%0A_(Note%3A%20This%20is%20meant%20to%20be%20an%20entry%20to%20%5BStack%20Overflow%27s%20C%2B%2B%20FAQ%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fc%2B%2B-faq).%20If%20you%20want%20to%20critique%20the%20idea%20of%20providing%20an%20FAQ%20in%20this%20form%2C%20then%20%5Bthe%20posting%20on%20meta%20that%20started%20all%20this%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F68647%2Fsetting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag)%20would%20be%20the%20place%20to%20do%20that.%20Answers%20to%20that%20question%20are%20monitored%20in%20the%20%5BC%2B%2B%20chatroom%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fchat.stackoverflow.com%2Frooms%2F10%2Fc-lounge)%2C%20where%20the%20FAQ%20idea%20started%20out%20in%20the%20first%20place%2C%20so%20your%20answer%20is%20very%20likely%20to%20get%20read%20by%20those%20who%20came%20up%20with%20the%20idea.)_%0A%3C%2Fsub%3E).

##### With line break after `<sub>`:

###### Markdown

```
<sub>
Note:  The answer is based on lessons from Scott Meyers' More Effective C++.  
_(Note: This is meant to be an entry to [Stack Overflow's C++ FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++-faq). If you want to critique the idea of providing an FAQ in this form, then [the posting on meta that started all this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68647/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag) would be the place to do that. Answers to that question are monitored in the [C++ chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/c-lounge), where the FAQ idea started out in the first place, so your answer is very likely to get read by those who came up with the idea.)_
</sub>
```

###### Rendered

<sub>Note:  The answer is based on lessons from Scott Meyers' More Effective C++.  
_(Note: This is meant to be an entry to [Stack Overflow's C++ FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++-faq). If you want to critique the idea of providing an FAQ in this form, then [the posting on meta that started all this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68647/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag) would be the place to do that. Answers to that question are monitored in the [C++ chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/c-lounge), where the FAQ idea started out in the first place, so your answer is very likely to get read by those who came up with the idea.)_</sub>

##### Without line break after `<sub>`:

###### Markdown

```
<sub>Note:  The answer is based on lessons from Scott Meyers' More Effective C++.  
_(Note: This is meant to be an entry to [Stack Overflow's C++ FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++-faq). If you want to critique the idea of providing an FAQ in this form, then [the posting on meta that started all this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68647/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag) would be the place to do that. Answers to that question are monitored in the [C++ chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/c-lounge), where the FAQ idea started out in the first place, so your answer is very likely to get read by those who came up with the idea.)_
</sub>
```

###### Rendered

<sub>Note:  The answer is based on lessons from Scott Meyers' More Effective C++.

*(Note: This is meant to be an entry to [Stack Overflow's C++ FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++-faq). If you want to critique the idea of providing an FAQ in this form, then [the posting on meta that started all this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68647/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag) would be the place to do that. Answers to that question are monitored in the [C++ chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/c-lounge), where the FAQ idea started out in the first place, so your answer is very likely to get read by those who came up with the idea.)*</sub>

Comment: I would honestly never have guessed that this was an intentional feature of the spec, and I'm still puzzled as to the intended use case.